# Compare two masks to determine which one is more of a rectangle shape than another -> Measuring Rectangularity

Tags: python, arrays, opencv

I have two masks containing two shapes that are close to being rectangle shapes.
Example mask (yellow):
[image]

Now I want to determine which one of those masks is closer to being an actual rectangle than another.

Is it possible to achieve it?

Comment: How do you quantify closer? If you go by angle, the purple rectangle is closer. "All squares are rectangles", right? But if you go by lengths of sides, the yellow trapezium is closer to being a square.

Comment: well I mean it's only one of the two squares (yellow), I haven't posted the second one, I will clarify it with an edit. Also, I quantify closer by going by angles.

Comment: Measure Rectangularity?

Comment: yes, that would be a goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the difference in area between the contour and the (rotated) rectangular bounding box. The one with the smallest difference in area is closest to rectangular.

See either cv2.boundingRect() or cv2.minAreaRect() for the area of the rectangle and cv2.findContours() and cv2.contourArea() for the object area.

https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga103fcbda2f540f3ef1c042d6a9b35ac7

https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga3d476a3417130ae5154aea421ca7ead9

https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0

https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga2c759ed9f497d4a618048a2f56dc97f1

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked like a charm :) I used ratio instead of difference tho.